# Merge duplicate keys in simple object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

How I can merge duplicate keys in the JS object.

---

Input:

```
{
 a: "1",
 b: "2",
 c: "3",
 c: "4",
 d: "5"
}
```

---

Output:

```
{
 a: "1",
 b: "2",
 c: ["3", "4"],
 d: "5"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If this object does not exist, I take Sublime and change it manually. Now its possible to create a new object and merge keys?

---

Input:

```
[
 {a: "1"},
 {b: "2"},
 {c: "3"},
 {c: "4"},
 {d: "5"}
]
```

---

Output:

```
[
 {a: "1"},
 {b: "2"},
 {c: ["3", "4"]},
 {d: "5"}
]
```

Comment: Loop, if exists -> ensure it's array -> add new value

Comment: How are you achieving an object with duplicate keys out of interest? Do you have a function already assigning the keys into the object ( and thus overwriting the previous key?)

Comment: it is not possible. in sloppy mode, the last same property wins (is taken), in strict mode, you get an error.

Comment: Are you manipulating the data before building the object? The only way to do this is before you build the object. As @NinaScholz said above it's not possible.

Comment: This is only possible in JSON, which is a string. Even then, this is not allowed and deseralising this JSON will lead to undefined behaviour - the resulting object *usually* has the second property "override" the first, but you might also get the first one being retained or an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A javascript object cannot have duplicated keys, so this will not work.

If instead you had an array of objects containing one or multiple keys and you wanted to merge all the objects to get your target structure, here is an example of how to do it:

```js
const arr = [
  { a: "1", b: "3" },
  { b: "2" },
  { c: "3", d: "4" },
  { c: "4" },
  { d: "5" }
];

const merged = arr.reduce((accum, obj) => {
  for (key in obj) {
    accum[key] = accum[key] ? [...accum[key], obj[key]] : obj[key];
  }
  return accum;
}, { });

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: You are right, instead I provided a complete example with a different input structure but giving the same output as the OP wanted, that could probably help

Comment: Thanks jo_va ! It is the right decision!

Answer (score 2):

If you create object like mentioned by you as follows -

```
{
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "3",
  c: "4",
  d: "5"
}
```

JavaScript engine will convert it as follows -

```
{
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "4",
  d: "5"
}
```

So you can not achieve what you mentioned.

Comment: I have a dictionary and it was created in C++. Yes, I know its impossible to create in JS, but it exists and it is alive)))) Maby I can transform this in the array of objects and after that manipulating them?

Comment: It is absolutely impossible for this object to exist. Are you sure it's a *JS object* and not *JSON*? Also, if you have this JSON - then it's incorrect by literally the definition. So C++ produces incorrect result. It should be treated the same as the program spitting out invalid XML or other invalid data and fixed, rather than pos-/pre-processing the wrong result into a correct one.

Comment: OK, I'll have to correct my previous comment. I had to check and the JSON standard doesn't actually impose a limitation of uniqueness. But it does leave what happens up to whatever tool is consuming this. Still, it doesn't change much - you either need to write something that processes JSON into the correct format for consumption or correct the other application to produce valid JSON for consumption directly.